# Battery life of Nikon Z 6/Z 7 for time lapse in manual mode

Tags: nikon, timelapse, mirrorless, battery-drain, nikon-z7

I am considering to purchase the Z 6 for time lapse photography and battery life is important.

Is it possible to deactivate all power-consuming features of the Nikon Z 6/Z 7 bodies when taking time lapses in manual mode? Since I neither need autofocus nor metering I would expect the battery life to actually be better than an equivalent DSLR because it has fewer moving parts.

As there is no need for the EVF or LCD to be running and both can be deactivated (the eye proximity sensor stays active), will the camera shut down its image sensor or will the camera still turn it on to perform calculations and gather (unused) data for metering and so on?

Comment: It does not clarify whether or not that is possible. Also, the CIPA standard battery tests are not very relevant for time lapse photography, so the numbers given in the manual are not really relevant. My D750 has a battery life of 1230 shots according to CIPA test standards while I can get 2500-3000 shots from the camera on a single charge when doing fast-shutter time lapse photography.

Comment: I should have been more precise. What I mean to say in the comment was that it didn't answer **my question**, which goes beyond simply LCD and EVF on/off. The "Prioritise viewfinder" option surely saves battery compared to an always-on option, but does it actually deactivate the sensor, turn metering off and so on? Your last line "I guess that the only ones to answer that competently are people who have tried that exact thing" is exactly why I raised this question.

Comment: Do you mean image sensor or proximity sensor with "deactivate the sensor". I see no reason why the image sensor could not be turned off and back on again when the EVF was turned on too (from a theoretical point of view), but whether Nikon has actually implemented it this way is the big question. If that is actually stated in the manual I must have missed it. Which page is this on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I approached Nikon in the end to clarify the situation. Unfortunately this is not possible and they recommended me to use a wall adapter. The Norwegian mountains are a bit short on power outlets, but at least it has been clarified now...

Comment: hmmm...isn't it possible to charge the Zs via USB? That way, a powerbank would help.

Comment: Unfortunately the battery in the Z-series cameras will only charge through USB while the camera is powered off. If they could be used while charging that would be awesome, but apparently that's not possible.